# Texmaker issue in LinuxMint

Tags: texmaker, linux

I am having this weird issue while using Texmaker in Linux Mint. The issue started happening only recently and I don't think I did any updates or changed/removed any program files.

As soon as I start to type `eq` inside the braces of `\label{}` the program closes itself. I have no clue what is happening. Please note that the text `\label{}` is highlighted. The program doesn't close when I type normal text or use math-mode.

Comment: Hello! I really don't know how to fix that (maybe just close and re-open `TeXmaker`?) but I can give you a (personal) suggestion: You could use instead of  `TeXmaker` `TeXstudio` – just simple type into a terminal `sudo apt-get install texstudio` and set is as the standard programm for opening `.tex` files.